# How can I pipe output of ffmpeg to ffplay?

Tags: bash, ffmpeg, pipe

How can I pipe the output of ffmpeg to ffplay?

At the moment I use a workaround in bash :

```
mkfifo spam
(ffplay spam 2> /dev/null &) ; capture /dev/stdout | ffmpeg -i - spam
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I do not know if it is `ffmpeg` that cannot output its data to stdout, or `ffplay` that cannot take its input from stdin.

If it is `ffmpeg` that cannot output its data to stdout:

```
capture /dev/stdout | ffmpeg -i - >(ffplay 2> /dev/null)
```

(You migth need to add a `-` argument to `ffplay` so it takes its input from stdin.)

If it is `ffplay` that cannot take its input from stdin:

```
ffplay <(capture /dev/stdout | ffmpeg -i -) 2> /dev/null
```

For more informations about the `<(command)` and `>(command)` construct, see the *Process Substitution* section of the bash manual.

Comment: for me this didnt work without explicitly specifying output format with "-f". as specified on https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html: "format is normally auto detected for input files and guessed from the file extension for output files". in given answer ffmpeg wont be able to guess output format. so i think ffmpeg should have "-f fmt" added to it.

Comment: ffmpeg 2.8.6 does support stdin input as mentioned in other answers. You can check for that support with: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12999674/ffmpeg-which-file-formats-support-stdin-usage

Comment: Can you elaborate what `capture` is? Ideally a link to a repo or the official website.

Answer (score 48):

```
ffmpeg -i input.avi <options> -f matroska - | ffplay -
```

will work; you need to set a container format for the output. This is normally set with ffmpeg looking at the extension you give the output, but here you have to set it manually with `-f`. I recommend matroska (MKV) because it can contain almost any video, so whatever you're transcoding it to should work perfectly well.

Note that if you are using Ubuntu 12.04, ffmpeg has been replaced by the libav fork, and you should use `avconv` and `avplay` instead; the syntax is otherwise identical. There is a sort-of ffmpeg there, but it's crippled by design.

Comment: Win10: Error occur as `pipe:: Invalid data found when processing inputK` in Power Shell, but works well in command prompt

Comment: The powershell invalid data thing is because of powershell parsing the binary data flowing through a | pipe as text, so ffplay in this case gets something it's not expecting. The solution is to run it in a cmd.exe to do the piping stuff, or powershell module Use-RawPipeline, while waiting for this to be implemented in powershell: https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/1908

Answer (score 19):

ffmpeg supports piping operations. See that section of the documentation [here](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-all.html#pipe).

I don't know how ffplay works, but to pipe the output of ffmpeg to standard output, you can add the pipe command to the end of the ffmpeg command. Example:

```
ffmpeg -i input.flv pipe:1 | ffplay -i -
```

Comment: thanks, i somehow missed that section of the man pages..  however i could not get this construct to work, the output filename needs to be removed from ffmpeg and input pipe added to ffplay args.  i will edit your post accordingly..

Comment: Thanks. As I said, I've never used ffplay before, but I know ffmpeg.

Comment: In my `man ffplay`, I cannot see `ffplay` supporting the `-i` switch - is it maybe `ffmpeg` only?

Comment: `pipe:1` vs `-`? `-` works on ffmpeg 2.8.6.

Comment: your correct that `ffplay` does not support `-i`, though the above might work/might have worked in the past.  This should also work: `ffmpeg -i input.flv <options> -f matroska - | ffplay -`

Answer (score 12):

looks like normal pipes work (at least in windows):

```
ffmpeg -i sintel.mpg -pix_fmt yuv420p -f rawvideo - | ffplay -f rawvideo -pix_fmt yuv420p -s 720x480 -
```

haven't tried it with more complicated input/output though...

```
ffmpeg -f dshow -i video=screen-capture-recorder -pix_fmt yuv420p -f mpegts - | ffplay -analyzeduration 10 -f mpegts -
```

is slightly faster startup

Comment: **I was getting `Unable to find a suitable output format for 'pipe:'` - I needed to specify a codec with `-f`.**

Comment: Works, but very low image quality

Comment: If it's low image quality then make sure that what you're initially capturing is high image quality (save it to a file first, etc.) it "should" be normal quality...