# Pipe VLC output to ffplay?

Tags: video, ffmpeg, vlc-media-player, pipe

I have a (broken) PC, where VLC plays videos on only the left half the screen, which seems related to OpenGL/drivers (see [here](http://forum.slitaz.org/topic/vlc-video-output-problems)). On the other hand, `ffplay` doesn't have the half-window problem, but can open only some videos I want to play.

So, similar to [How can I pipe output of ffmpeg to ffplay?](https://superuser.com/questions/322216/how-can-i-pipe-output-of-ffmpeg-to-ffplay), I thought of piping VLC to `ffplay`; and I got this far (I'm using [this video](http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Rent_an_Ambassador.ogv)):

```
$ cvlc Rent_an_Ambassador.ogv --sout '#transcode{vcodec=IYUV}:std{access=file,mux=raw,dst=-}' | ffplay -f rawvideo -s 398x224 pipe:-
...
Warning: call to srand(1369860697)
Warning: call to rand()
Blocked: call to unsetenv("DBUS_ACTIVATION_ADDRESS")
Blocked: call to unsetenv("DBUS_ACTIVATION_BUS_TYPE")
[0x98f4b64] dummy interface: using the dummy interface module...
[0x9903254] mux_dummy mux: Open
[rawvideo @ 0x98bf890]Estimating duration from bitrate, this may be inaccurate
Input #0, rawvideo, from 'pipe:-':
  Duration: N/A, start: 0.000000, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0.0: Video: rawvideo, yuv420p, 398x224, 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc
```

So, basically `ffplay` it picks up that VLC's `IYUV` should be `yuv420p`, as I read in [Libav user questions and discussions - Re: Scale image from 4:2:2 to 4:2:0](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.video.ffmpeg.libav.user/7887)

> Note that YUV420P is a.k.a. I420 and IYUV.

... unfortunately, the video output is all wrong:

[image: bad video]

Note that if I don't specify the size for `ffplay`, it fails with:

```
picture size invalid (0x0)
    Last message repeated 1 times
[rawvideo @ 0x9c6f890]Could not find codec parameters (Video: rawvideo, yuv420p)
[rawvideo @ 0x9c6f890]Estimating duration from bitrate, this may be inaccurate
pipe:-: could not find codec parameters
```

So, my question is:

- Would anyone know of a proper command line for piping from `vlc` to `ffplay` - using raw video?
- Is there a way to make `vlc` play audio as usual, and pipe its video output as raw video to `ffplay` (so as to avoid the overhead of muxing video and audio into a new format, which ffplay would have to additionally demux?)

---

EDIT: Here's one command line that does provide proper video with test file as above (via [The VideoLAN Forums • Sending YUV data to a pipe under windows](http://forum.videolan.org/viewtopic.php?f=14&t=87966)):

```
cvlc Rent_an_Ambassador.ogv --vout=yuv --yuv-yuv4mpeg2 --yuv-file=/dev/stdout | ffplay pipe:-
```

However:

- `ffplay` segfaults when I try to unpack some other videos with `vlc`
- For yet a third category of videos, `vlc` will not export FPS setting - so `ffplay` will start, show a frame, and then freeze display (and you'd have to continually scroll the mouse button, so the video window refreshes). Note here that you cannot [force ffplay frame rate for timeless containers](http://ffmpeg-users.933282.n4.nabble.com/Force-ffplay-frame-rate-for-timeless-containers-td2502659.html) - and when doing `--yuv-file` (instead of `--sout`) the `--sout-transcode-fps` will not apply (from the `vlc` side of things)

Comment: It irritates me that `ffplay` wouldn't be able to play something VLC can. Especially Ogg Theora (?) video. Is there a chance you could supply a small test sample?

Comment: Thanks for the comment, @slhck - the video is linked in the post (it's from Wikimedia Commons). Actually, both `vlc` and `ffplay` can play this file fine - the question is about what format to choose, so one pipes decoded output from `vlc` into `ffplay`... Cheers!

Comment: Have you tried adding in the `--rawvid-chroma` parameter to the call to `VLC`?  Try adding `--rawvid-chroma=YV12` before the pipe (you can also try `UYVY` or `I422`, but I think the parameter should be `YV12` for YUV240p.

Comment: Thanks for the comment @Breakthrough - tried it now, but doesn't work, and probably it shouldn't (note that `--rawvid-chroma` is option for "Raw video demuxer" == "player"; however here VLC plays "OGV", not "raw video") .. that is why the chroma should have been fixed with `vcodec=IYUV` in the very first attempt, but for some reason isn't. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried disabling hardware video acceleration in VLC? This might fix the half-screen problem.

[image]

<sub>Yes I realize this isn't the question asked, but it seems to be an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).</sub>

Comment: Thanks for that @DarthAndroid - of course I have, among the first things :) Doesn't work - the linked Slitaz post confirms that loading 'nvidia' driver for X11 was what solved the issue; but on my system, `radeon.ko.gz` is loaded, and X11 doesn't accept it in its setup; which is why I'm looking at this workaround (which actually works - for those pipes that don't segfault with `avi` as in OP edit)... Basically, I just want to use `vlc` as audio player and video demuxer/decoder - and `ffplay` as basically just a "projection screen" :) Cheers!