# FFPLAY/FFMPEG (Capture Device)

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm copying some VHS tapes with my Windows 10 computer using FFPLAY/FFMPEG (Capture Device) in a Batch File.

FFPLAY can view the tape this way, and it's great.

```
FFPLAY.EXE -hide_banner -f dshow -rtbufsize 1024M -i video="Roxio Video Capture USB":audio="Line (Roxio Video Capture USB)"
```

and this will Convert to MP4, and it's great too.  [I had some Synch problems but I added "-async 1 -vsync 1" and it's OK]

```
ffmpeg -fflags +genpts -async 1 -vsync 1 -f dshow -rtbufsize 1024M -i video="Roxio Video Capture USB":audio="Line (Roxio Video Capture USB)" -filter:v fps=29.97 -aspect 4:3 -c:v libx264 -preset ultrafast -tune zerolatency -crf 20 -pix_fmt yuv420p -c:a aac -strict -2 -ac 2 -b:a 128k -t 03:00:00 -async 1 -vsync 1 "Good Movie.MP4"
```

BUT, is there anyway to both runs simultaneously so I can view the tape and stop the Convert?

here's the Batch File:

```
@ECHO OFF
cd /d C:\Movies

Cls
@Echo.
@Echo.
@Echo.
@Echo Converting
title File Good Movie.MP4
@Echo.

FFPLAY.EXE -hide_banner -f dshow -rtbufsize 1024M -i video="Roxio Video Capture USB":audio="Line (Roxio Video Capture USB)"

@Echo.
@ping 127.0.0.1 -n 2 -w 2000 > nul
@ping 127.0.0.1 -n %1% -w 2000> nul

ffmpeg -fflags +genpts -async 1 -vsync 1 -f dshow -rtbufsize 1024M -i video="Roxio Video Capture USB":audio="Line (Roxio Video Capture USB)" -filter:v fps=29.97 -aspect 4:3 -c:v libx264 -preset ultrafast -tune zerolatency -crf 20 -pix_fmt yuv420p -c:a aac -strict -2 -ac 2 -b:a 128k -t 03:00:00 -async 1 -vsync 1 "Good Movie.MP4"

@Echo.
@Echo.

pause
```

Answer (score 0):

---

*The examples given here were created with the references at the end of this answer and some light testing with another DirectShow device. They may still need modification. (I unfortunately do not own the same device you do).*

*Note that `^` can be used in batch files to break up long lines without affecting execution, which is why it appears in the examples below.*

---

FFmpeg supports multiple outputs. These can be added by simply placing another output at the end of a given `ffmpeg` command.

For instance, assuming the command:

```
ffmpeg -fflags +genpts -async 1 -vsync 1 -f dshow -rtbufsize 1024M ^
-i video="Roxio Video Capture USB":audio="Line (Roxio Video Capture USB)" ^
-filter:v fps=29.97 -aspect 4:3 -c:v libx264 -preset ultrafast ^
-tune zerolatency -crf 20 -pix_fmt yuv420p -c:a aac -strict -2 -ac 2 ^
-b:a 128k -t 03:00:00 -async 1 -vsync 1 "Good Movie.MP4"
```

You could try adding ex.:

```
-f matroska -
```

As an additional output. So:

```
ffmpeg -fflags +genpts -async 1 -vsync 1 -f dshow -rtbufsize 1024M ^
-i video="Roxio Video Capture USB":audio="Line (Roxio Video Capture USB)" ^
-filter:v fps=29.97 -aspect 4:3 -c:v libx264 -preset ultrafast ^
-tune zerolatency -crf 20 -pix_fmt yuv420p -c:a aac -strict -2 -ac 2 ^
-b:a 128k -t 03:00:00 -async 1 -vsync 1 "Good Movie.MP4" -f matroska -
```

The special output `-` could then be piped (`|`) to `fflpay` and viewed with ex.:

```
ffplay -i -
```

So the final command for your script might look like:

```
ffmpeg -hide_banner -fflags +genpts -async 1 -vsync 1 -f dshow ^
-rtbufsize 1024M -i video="Roxio Video Capture USB":audio="Line (Roxio Video Capture USB)" ^
-filter:v fps=29.97 -aspect 4:3 -c:v libx264 -preset ultrafast ^
-tune zerolatency -crf 20 -pix_fmt yuv420p -c:a aac -strict -2 -ac 2 ^
-b:a 128k -t 03:00:00 -async 1 -vsync 1 "Good Movie.MP4" -f matroska - ^
| ffplay -hide_banner -i -
```

This would replace the separate `ffplay` and `ffmpeg` commands in your script above.

---

One thing to be aware of is that using e.g. `-f matroska` could slow things down. Another format option that may *potentially* yield better performance results is `rawvideo` ex.:

```
-r 30 -pix_fmt yuv420p -f rawvideo -
```

So e.g.:

```
ffmpeg -fflags +genpts -async 1 -vsync 1 -f dshow -rtbufsize 1024M ^
-i video="Roxio Video Capture USB":audio="Line (Roxio Video Capture USB)" ^
-filter:v fps=29.97 -aspect 4:3 -c:v libx264 -preset ultrafast ^
-tune zerolatency -crf 20 -pix_fmt yuv420p -c:a aac -strict -2 -ac 2 ^
-b:a 128k -t 03:00:00 -async 1 -vsync 1 "Good Movie.MP4" ^
-r 30 -pix_fmt yuv420p -f rawvideo -
```

The corresponding `ffplay` command might then look like e.g.:

```
ffplay -f rawvideo -pix_fmt yuv420p -video_size 1234x1234 -framerate 30 -i -
```

And as a final piping example:

```
ffmpeg -hide_banner -fflags +genpts -async 1 -vsync 1 -f dshow ^
-rtbufsize 1024M -i video="Roxio Video Capture USB":audio="Line (Roxio Video Capture USB)" ^
-filter:v fps=29.97 -aspect 4:3 -c:v libx264 -preset ultrafast ^
-tune zerolatency -crf 20 -pix_fmt yuv420p -c:a aac -strict -2 -ac 2 ^
-b:a 128k -t 03:00:00 -async 1 -vsync 1 "Good Movie.MP4" -r 30 ^
-pix_fmt yuv420p -f rawvideo - | ffplay -hide_banner -f rawvideo ^
-pix_fmt yuv420p -video_size 1234x1234 -framerate 30 -i -
```

Be aware that ex. `-video_size 1234x1234` in `ffplay` (above) is just an example. `rawvideo` is sensitive to having the right values to display an image correctly. So I might suggest trying the resolution of the video you are working with first.

Similarly, the `30`s in `-r 30` and `-framerate 30` are just examples. They may or may not work for you. Also, the `-r` option (the output frame rate) in `-r 30 -pix_fmt yuv420p -f rawvideo -` isn't required but it seemed helpful for performance during testing. You may also be able to omit the `-framerate` option in the `ffplay` portion, but this didn't work well for me either. I would consider leaving in both `-r` and `-framerate` and trying to set these to the same frame rate as your original video.

---

*I am not certain if `-filter:v fps=29.97` might affect frame rates or not in this instance, but you can certainly try `29.97` as well.*

---

*References*

- [How can I pipe the output of ffmpeg to ffplay?](https://superuser.com/questions/322216/how-can-i-pipe-output-of-ffmpeg-to-ffplay) (Super User)
- [Creating multiple outputs](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Creating%20multiple%20outputs) (trac.ffmpeg.org)
- [`rawvideo` Format](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#rawvideo) (FFmpeg Official Documentation)

Comment: Hmm. matroska has several seconds of delay which makes it useless for me, and rawvideo immediate results in `pipe:: Invalid data found when processing input` and a broken pipe.  What about tee?

Answer (score 0):

**Your code worked great!**   it worked faster to get it working that you did telling me what to do.  I know it did a lot of time to show me - I really, really owe you and here's a "Nickle" big guy <<5¢>> for helping me...  I am still playing around testing but wanted to thank you

I modified a little code; one is to name the video file to show the Date/Time & I like to see what FFMPEG is doing while Converting to MP4.

You mention the first code might slow things down, it does, the audio stutters a little on the preview, but the convertion seems ok.

I tried the 2nd one ["Good Movie.MP4" -r 30 -pix_fmt yuv420p -f rawvideo - ] but it has problems, I added a PrintScreen JPG to see what it's doing?

I didn't know about  ^  used in batch files and FFmpeg supports multiple outputs

errors:
real-time buffer [Roxio Video Capture USB] [video input] too full or near too full (75% of size: 1024000000 [rtbufsize parameter])! frame dropped!
Past duration 0.984367 too large

Batch File for now...

---

@echo off
setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

set today=!date:/=-!
set now=!time::=-!
set millis=!now:*.=!
set now=!now:.%millis%=!

echo.  set str VHS-!today!_!now!.mp4

ffmpeg.exe    -fflags +genpts -async 1 -vsync 1 -f dshow ^
-rtbufsize 1024M -i video="Roxio Video Capture USB":audio="Line (Roxio Video Capture USB)" ^
-filter:v fps=29.97 -aspect 4:3 -c:v libx264 -preset ultrafast ^
-tune zerolatency -crf 20 -pix_fmt yuv420p -c:a aac -strict -2 -ac 2 ^
-b:a 128k -t 03:00:00 -async 1 -vsync 1 "VHS-!today!_!now!.mp4" -f matroska - | FFPLAY.EXE  -hide_banner -i -

pause

---

Comment: Upvoting or accepting answers would be much better than a "Nickle". It is one reason your questions get ignored. See the [tour] to understand how this site works which will help you get answers, and get answers faster.